# How do I access my Windows 7 files?

Tags: partitioning, windows-7

The question is a little more complicated than the title may suggest.

After a bad experience with Windows 10, I tried to downgrade, long story short, Windows 7 is borked. I installed Ubuntu, creating a 20GB EXT4 and 6GB swap partition in the process. I'm keen to access the rest of the 700GB or so of files that are still swimming around the hard drive, but am unsure of how to proceed.

When I installed it, I left the last partition as 'unallocated', which is where everything else is. Does that mean that the data is lost? Or is it still possible to re-allocate that space and find the files inside?

I'd greatly appreciate any help

Comment: In the file manager click the icon for that Windows partition to mount it. Then you can transfer files to external hdd or your Ubuntu partition, if the space allows so.

Comment: I'm a complete newb at Ubuntu. When I installed it, I left the last partition as 'unallocated', which is where everything else is. Does that mean that the data is lost? Or is it still possible to re-allocate that space and find the files inside? Thanks!

Comment: Who or what has "unallocated" it? It should have been shown as a NTFS partition (windows, msdos, whatever gparted says). If you deleted the partition before creating the linux ones (and not resized it), you probably have lost a lot. You can try http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu